# How do I use git-new-workdir on windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash, branch, msysgit

I have a repo that has two branches, which i would like to work on simultaneously.
After some reading I found git has a script [`git-new-workdir`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir).

---

Im trying run use the script from the [git for windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) bash but get the following error.

```
$ git-new-workdir
sh: git-new-workdir: command not found
```

---

How do I use this script on **windows**?

Comment: Note: with Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015), it will work on Windows (or any other OS). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30185898/6309).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to some of the commands in the `git-new-workdir` functions not existing on windows, the script won't work.

---

I have found this windows port of the script. Works great for me.

https://github.com/joero74/git-new-workdir

Answer (score 4):

Git 2.5 (Q2 2015) will replace `contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir` with an official native Git command **which works on any OS** (including Windows).

The [release notes mentions](https://github.com/git/git/blob/22aca1b3ac10af7188dccf033b44a36926f04d4b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt#L25-L27):

> does not rely on symbolic links and make sharing of objects and refs safer by making the borrowee and borrowers aware of each other.

That is because the multiple working trees are "linked", or actually recorded in the main repo new `$GIT_DIR/worktrees` folder.

See "[**Multiple working directories with Git?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)" for more.

Answer (score 1):

On my installation, the script file is located in `/usr/share/git/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir`.

Perhaps if it's not installed in that version of `git`, you can just download its [raw form](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir) and run it with `bash /path/to/git-new-workdir`. At your preference you can also install it in `/usr/local/bin` changing permissions when necessary.