# Using "git svn" with two working trees

Tags: git-svn, tortoisegit, git-clone

I am starting to use git as a Subversion client at work. For now I've been using  TortoiseGit, more or less how I used to use TortoiseSvn, but with *local* commits, branches, merges, rebases, cherry picking.

It is a big project and switching a branch and recompiling everything takes too long. This is why I want to have two (or more) working trees corresponding to two branches of the Subversion project.

I wonder if it is possible to share the .git folder for the two working trees (its 5GB), or I need to clone the repository or maybe checkout it again from subversion (it took several hours).

From the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client) it seems that interaction between two git repositories will not work well if they interact with svn as well (I don't know if this applies to my case):

> Don’t rewrite your history and try to push again, and don’t push to a parallel Git repository to collaborate with fellow Git developers at the same time. Subversion can have only a single linear history, and confusing it is very easy. If you’re working with a team, and some are using SVN and others are using Git, make sure everyone is using the SVN server to collaborate – doing so will make your life easier.

I would like to have a single repository with all svn branches and all my local branches and I would like have several working trees to avoid the need to rebuild everything after switching branches. Is that possible?

I don't know much about "bare" or "shared" repos, remotes and clones, a basic example to set this up would be very helpful.

Comment: Tortoise sounds like Windows. At least on Linux/Unix there is git-new-workdir which sets a few symlinks/hardlinks to share a sngle .git dir over multiple working dirs, see http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows. I found that https://github.com/joero74/git-new-workdir (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016143/how-do-i-use-git-new-workdir-on-windows). It works! I had to start "cmd" as administrator, add git to the path, and run the script. It created the links and checked out the code. Now If I create a branch in one working tree, I can see it in the log of the other working tree.

Comment: @johannes: if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally did:

As johannes suggested, there is a script that solves my problem on Linux (http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/). But I am on Windows:

- download the Windows port of the script from https://github.com/joero74/git-new-workdir
- open a `cmd` as Administrator (git installs a `Git bash` that won't work with this script, you need to do it with `cmd`)
- Add git to the path if you don't have it. In my case `set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"`
- execute the script. In my case I have a folder called Project (that has a .git folder in it): `git-new-workdir.cmd .\Project .\Project2`

This creates a new folder Project2, with a working tree and a folder called .git. This .git folder has links to the original Project/.git so if I do some `git svn fetch` or create local branches or anything, both "copies" are updated at the same time (without `push` or `pull`). The working trees are different: if I switch branch in one, the other doesn't change and I can work on different branches at the same time.

I just need to remember where the original .git is and never delete it.